# Vue router async route guard progress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm doing async work in my router's navigation guard:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  somethingAsync().done(next)
})
```

Does the router expose anything to tell me that it's currently "loading"? Or do I need to keep track of it myself? Right now the content will pop up in`<router-view></router-view>` once the async work is completed. My current solution is to keep track of active work in my Vuex store and show a loading element next to the router view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do to achieve what I think you are trying to is this:

- Use Axios or something else that has interceptors
  https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios
- Have a component that have a counter of pending requests. When that counter is higher than 0, show the loading element.
- After that all you have to do is configure the interceptors so that when a request is made the counter goes up, and when a response
  is received the counter goes down.

I could show you some code if you need.

Comment: Yeah that it what I do in my Vuex store today :) I was curious if something was built in so I'm not reinventing the wheel